# Measuring change over time using panel data

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, panel-data

I have just started my first job out of university, and my first assignment is to measure change in grades over time for a group of students. Since this is my very first job, I really want to do a great job, but since no one at my job is familiar with panel data, I need some help. I have spent the day searching all over the internet but haven't found what I am looking for, and therefore I am now asking for your help.

My data consist of approximately 100 students who attends a special kind of school due to a variety of problems. Over a course of a year the students are being tested three times to establish if they are are actually learning anything. My job is to test whether the students are improving, and if they are by how much. I do know how to test whether the students are improving, but what regression model should I use in testing how much the students are improving over time? My own guess is just to use OLS, but is that the correct model to use when working with panel data?

I feel like, this should be really simple, but my brain just isn't working correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a mixed effects model or a marginal model to account for the fact that measurements on the same student over time are correlated. Working with OLS can be inefficient in settings with correlated data, and if on top of that you have missing data that are of the missing at random type, OLS can be biased.

For more info, you can check [my course notes on regression models for repeated measurements data](http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't learned a lot about mixed effects models, which may be the reason why I haven't been able to figure it out by myself. So also thank you for the link to your course notes. 
I have another question. In my dataset I only have id, time and test score for each id and time period. Does that mean I just have to use time as my explanatory variable? :)

Comment: Logically yes you will need to include as an explanatory variable to see changes in your score over time.